# Multiple Correct Answers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I have had several questions now where multiple answer are correct. It would be nice to mark all the answer that are correct as so and then leave it up to the votes to decided which is the best of the correct ones.

Answer (score 9):

**Choose the best answer**

Correctness is only one part of the answer. Choose the answer that was, as an answer, most useful to you. Maybe it's because of formatting or means of address. But no, having "multiple" correct answers is what upvotes are for.

Comment: Also, if there are two identical correct answers - choose the first in time; people are NOT supposed to submit the same answer again but instead to vote up/comment on/expand and improve a previous answer they agree with.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it a correct question ?**

I believe it is written somewhere in the stone tablets that questions are actually supposed to have one correct answer. If the question objectively accepts multiple correct distinct answers, it could be that a reconsideration is in order then.

Comment: In math or programming that would be reasonable, but here questions that have only 1 correct answer are a rarely-achieved ideal.